# Linux: Read string from a file and execute commands in other scipt

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm a newbie to Linux/coding/scripting.

I currently have a script to start services of OBIEE application on RHEL 5.5.This is a sample from my script:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -e "Starting Node Manager..."
    $ORACLE_FMW/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh > startNodemanager.log  2>&1 &
    sleep 30
    echo -e "Starting Weblogic Server...."
    $ORACLE_FMW/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh > startWeblogic.log 2>&1 &
```

As you can see I'm trying to start 2 services one after the other using timeframe gap of 30seconds, independent of whether 1st service (Node Manager) starts or fails.

Instead of using static time gap in the script, I want to execute/start 2nd service(weblogic), based on output(of startNodemanager.log) from 1st service(NodeManager).

When NodeManager starts successfully, it ends its log file  with certain string. EX:

"INFO: Secure socket listener started on port 9556"

So is it possible to write some command in my script (in place of time frame) that reads this string from output log and executes 2nd service only upon receiving desired string, till then holding off execution of 2nd service.

Thanks.

=======================

EDIT:

I have updated the script as suggested by yingted below.
It did not fix my issue yet. read is holding off triggering the 2nd service but it's failing to trigger it even after desired message is recorded in the log. My updated script looks like this using your command:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -e "Starting Node Manager..."
    $ORACLE_FMW/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh > startNodemanager.log  2>&1 &
    read -r < <(tail -f startNodemanager.log | grep --line-buffered -Fx -- 'INFO: Secure socket listener started on port 9556')
    echo -e "Starting Weblogic Server...."
    $ORACLE_FMW/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh > startWeblogic.log 2>&1 &
```

Problem might be with the message in the log.
Actually the message 'INFO: Secure socket listener started on port 9556' is preceded with a time stamp in the log.

Is there anyway I could add timestamp as wild card entry?

Answer (score 1):

Your second process should follow the first one.

```
read -r < <(tail -f startNodemanager.log | grep --line-buffered 'INFO: Secure socket listener started on port 9556$')
```

The read command waits until `startNodemanager.log` contains a line ending in `INFO: Secure socket listener started on port 9556`.

`read` also accepts a `-t timeout` flag, which exits and sets `$?` greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded. If it instead succeeds, `read` returns 0.

Comment: You could add a timeout to `read` so this doesn't hang if the first process is unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yingted
Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. Please read my main post for updated script and comments.

Comment: You can just check if a line ends with that string.